# Is it (under FIPS) possible to generate a CSR for an asymmetric key with usage=WRAP?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, hsm, fips

To clarify:  The FIPS module Security Policy lists using RSA keys for wrap/unwrap.  FIPS is a moving target, and the state of the requirements when the CMVP approved module went through the process was such, that a given key's "usage" had to be a single purpose (sign/verify, OR wrap/unwrap, OR key agreement).

So we have this conceptual wrap/unwrap RSA key, allowed-but-not-approved, and we want to get a cert for it.  We generate a CSR ... which requires that the key in question be used to sign a hash of the CSR information, as proof that we have the private key for the public key found in the CSR.

But the module should not allow this, because this is a usage=wrap key, not a usage=sign/verify key.

If it works, my assumption is that the module is waffling on what it allows itself to do with the key -- yes, this is usage=WRAP but (oh-my-word-look-over-THERE) uses it to sign the CSR under the hood.

So long as the module doesn't allow the state machine to be violated, from the viewpoint of "outside" the module this would be a permitted behavior.

Either/Or, I missed something critical to the process/am over-thinking it.

Comment: Well yeah, 'wrap is for wrap'.  Says so right on the label.  But if a key is for wrapping, basically an encryption, won't the infrastructure prevent you from *signing* the CSR? "It's not a signing key, it's a wrapping key".

Comment: But then... *signing* is also 'basically an encryption' :/

Comment: (Please do not focus on the) Contrived use-case: If a 3d party wants to send me a symmetric key, which is used e.g. as a database encryption key for the DB they are giving me access to, I can send them my public key to wrap the symmetric key with.  How do they know that it is my public key? Because I send a cert, not just the public key.  Back to the question:  To get that public CA signed cert, I need to generate a CSR, which brings me back to... will a FIPS certified module actually allow me to generate the CSR, since that requires a signature step, but the key is usage == wrap.

Comment: Bingo!  That CMC reference is perfect for my quandary.  Feel free to post an answer and I'll upvote it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A certificate request is signed so that the CA knows you have the private key corresponding to the public key you wish certified.  The traditional way of doing this in PKCS#10 is to sign your request with your private key.  However, as you say, you cannot sign with a key that is flagged within your cryptographic module for key wrapping.

You have two options:

1. You need a cryptographic module which permits multipurpose keys (e.g. [Policy #10 on Luna HSMs](https://thalesdocs.com/gphsm/luna/7/docs/network/Content/admin_partition/policies/partition_capabilities_and_policies.htm)); or,
2. You need to provide proof of possession of the private key without signing, assuming your CA accepts requests in formats other than PKCS#10. CMC has an example of this in [Section 6.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5272.html#section-6.7).

Comment: The q/a on this enlightened me to the fact that I was asking the wrong question. Not "how do I get a cert" but "how do I guarantee proof of possession" which may or may not entail having a cert.  thank you!